# Objective-C Object gone due to memory management in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, memory, nsmutablearray, zombie-process

I have a problem regarding the memory management when adding objects to a `NSMutableArray`. Weird thing is that it's all working fine for the first 8 objects I add, but when adding a 9th, the application crashes when retrieving this object.

```
UploadStatus *status = [[UploadStatus alloc] initWithStatus:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %d", NSLocalizedString(@"uploadPictureSucceeded", @""), pic_id] 
                                                 andImageInProgress:nil 
                                                    imageForSuccess:nil 
                                                     imageForFailed:nil];
[self.delegate notify:status];
[status release];
```

This is being done on several places with different texts. But this object contains my status that I display in a `UITableView`.

In the `notify` method of the delegate I add the `UploadStatus` object to the `NSMutableArray` and I reload the `UITableView` that shows the objects inside that array.

The first 8 times I add a `UploadStatus` object to the array and reload the table, it shows correctly. But the 9th time I get the error **[CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5c655c0**. This error occurs when reloading the table in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Weird thing is that it **always** shows that the objects inside the `NSMutableArray` are out of scope like in this screenshot:

[image]

Nevertheless if I fetch the item, convert it into the `UploadStatus` class and get the `status` from it, it all goes smoothly (for the first 8 objects).

Does anybody have a clue why it goes wrong after adding the 9th `UploadStatus` object to the `NSMutableArray`?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You should show how you are building the NSMutableArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this code:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %d", NSLocalizedString(@"uploadPictureSucceeded", @""), pic_id]
```

You aren't retaining the string, so it goes away on the next execution of the run loop. You're getting lucky with the first 8. They happen to not get overwritten for some reason, or possibly some other object is retaining them. But the 9th one isn't and you finally see the results of the mistake.

You need for the UploadStatus object to retain that string (and later release it).

Comment: How do you know (without seeing the code) that initWithStatus doesn't retain the NSString?  By standard Objective-C coding conventions it should.

Comment: I don't, but judging by what happens, and how often I've made that mistake myself, I'm making on educated guess. You're correct that I don't know for sure.

Comment: He was actually right. Changing my `initStatus:`... to contain `status = [_status retain];` actually solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I note that you're directly accessing your ivars in this block of code rather than using accessors. This is almost certainly the root of your problem (it is the #1 cause of memory management problems in ObjC). Switch to accessors and most of your memory management problems will go away.

You should also go ahead and run the static analyzer (Build>Analyze). It might shed light. The problem is likely not in the above code; it's somewhere that you're storing something, most likely in an an ivar.

Comment: It's perfectly legit to access ivars directly for reading from within the class.

Comment: As you note "for reading," I assume you agree that for writing, accessors are absolutely critical. Having different rules for reading and writing complicates audit and makes the code non-symmetrical, while providing little benefit. The danger of people writing directly to ivars greatly outweighs the advantages of reading directly from them. There are several cases where reading directly from ivars is not safe (multi-threaded code is the most common), making it even more advantageous to get out of the habit of touching ivars directly, even for reading.

Comment: Unfortunately, Objective-C is "non_symmetrical" in the best of cases.  You always use accessors, *except* in init and dealloc, eg.  And, of course, not every ivar is a property with accessors (sometimes for good reason, to make the ivar a little less "public").

Comment: Mmm, what's wrong with writing to ivars? And with ivars you mean general variables? You should always use accessors as in `self.status = @"pending";` for instance? And why?

Comment: @HotLicks, you can (and should) generate private properties. I recommend never generating a "naked" (non-property) ivar at all.

Comment: @Jules, because `self.status = foo;` will always do correct memory management, and `status = foo;` is incorrect if `status` is a retained ivar (but correct otherwise, and you can't tell from the code without going and checking the header). `status=foo;` may both leak and crash. This is in fact the leading cause of ObjC crashes. Under ARC, the question is more debatable, but I still believe that the balance favors accessors, when you consider lazy-load ivars, KVO, and setters with side-effects.